# Strings comparison in C++

Tags: c++, search, comparison

Somebody helped me that i should change the `char[]` to `string`, but I am still having problem comparing the strings imputed by the user. I am not sure if I have to use `fstream` or something else. `getline` did not really help me since it shows errors depending on what it is inside the getline.

```
void search (competitor competitors[], int broi)    
{
string country;
string name;
char choice;
bool flag;

do{ 

    cout << "\n\n Input Country: " << endl; 
    fstream country;    

    cout << " Input name: " << endl;

    fstream name;
    flag = false; 

    for(int i=0; i<count; i++) 
    {
        if( country==competitors[i].country && name==competitors[i].name)
        {
            cout << "found one" << endl;
            flag = true; 
        }
    }
    if (flag == false)  

    cout << " New search (Y/N)?: ";
    cin >> izbor;

}while(choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y');
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fstream country;
```

This declares a new variable named `country` of type `fstream`. Probably not what you want.

You should try:

```
getline(std::cin, country);
```

instead. And you have the same issue with `name`.

Also:

```
flag = true;
```

better call `break` directly.

And:

```
cin >> izbor;
```

should probably be: `cin >> choice;`

Comment: Also, there's an outer `string country` and an inner `fstream country`. Same thing with `name`.

Comment: @chris: yes, which is why I think that `fstream country` was some tentative to put something country, for some reason.